# How to Convert That Java 1.7 Code to Java 1.6?

Tags: java, java-7, java-6

I am converting an existing Java 1.7 project into 1.6. I have changed diamond operations and try with resources. However 1.7 has some File operations capability that 1.6 does not have. How can I change that lines of code into 1.6:

```
OutputStream fileStream = Files.newOutputStream(path); //there is no Files class
java.nio.file.Files.createDirectories(outputRoot.toPath()); //there is not toPath() method

also Path class
```

Comment: Use Apache Commons IO or Guava. Or use `java.io` classes directly.

Comment: Well, have you tried looking at the implementations of either of these methods? Also, the first line can probably be replaced with `new FileOutputStream(path)` and the second line can be replaced with `outputRoot.mkdirs()`

Comment: Out of curiosity - why would you do this?

Comment: @AndreyChaschev I have a library written for Java 1.7 and my servers have 1.6. I do not change the server's Java version and I have to use that library.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis what do you mean with java.io classes?

Comment: I mean the classes that are in `java.io` package, ex. `File`, `FileInputStream`, etc.

Comment: @kamaci thank you. I'm just thinking when will lambda meet Java EE? Not earlier than 2017 judging by your case...

Comment: @AndreyChaschev you may be right. Because there are many libraries that will not be compatible to existing codes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace the first line with:

```
OutputStream fileStream = new FileOutputStream(path);
```

And you could replace the second line with:

```
outputRoot.mkdirs();
```